# Evaluating string in Arcade 'if' statement?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcade

I'm tasked with building an Arcade expression that evaluates whether a string field includes given characters, and returns values accordingly. Attribute `UTILITY_GROUP` may be `E`, `EU`, `G`, or `GU`. To cut down on the number of comparisons required, I had hoped to do something like (pseudocode):

```js
var utility = $feature.UTILITY_GROUP
if ('E' in utility) {
  return 'electric'
}
if ('G' in utility) {
  return 'gas'
}
```

Is there a way to express "if string includes [character]" in Arcade? I didn't see anything [documented in the logical operators](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/guide/logic/#if-statements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just done a quick test in ArcGIS Pro 2.1.  A `Find('text to find', 'text to search in', 0)` seems to work.  I've only tested on a handful of features, so I'm not sure what performance is like in a large dataset.

```js
var utility = $feature.UTILITY_GROUP;
if (Find('E', utility, 0) > 0) {
  return 'electric'
  };
if (Find('G', utility, 0) > 0) {
  return 'gas'
  };
```

See [ArcGIS Arcade - Text Functions - Find](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/text_functions/#find)